# Stateless Application Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm creating a Spring boot application with Spring Web,Spring Security and Spring social. The application contains rest services that utilizes basic authentication for security. I"m trying to configure Spring to make the application stateless, however when I use the browser to make requests to the web services the browser prompts for user credential but all prior request use the same user credential because of session creation. I have configured the application to stop this from happening but still having the problem. \

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**")
            .hasRole("USER")
            .andBasic();
    }

    @override
    protected void configure(AuthenticatioinManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("some@gmail.com")
            .password("12345")
            .role("USER");
    }
}
```

What should I change or add to get this functionality.

Answer (score 4):

Spring security is based on something called the SecurityContext. This something is a ThreadLocal, e.g only exists on one thread at a time. Each request will be on it's own thread and will have no access to any protected resource unless that SecurityContext is set to contain the appropriate roles. So even though you just logged in, which behind the scenes inserted roles into the SecurityContext, that security context is gone just as though it had been a different user. Tokens are how you want to deal with this issue. Or base64 encode your username and password into every request, whatever floats your boat.

Answer (score -1):

Look at this:

```
    http
  .sessionManagement()
  .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
  .and()
  .csrf().disable()
  .authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll() //allow CORS option calls
  .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
  .anyRequest().authenticated()
  .and()
  .httpBasic();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Explaining your code in the answer might be a bit more helpful to future readers, or people with a similar problems.